# How to get retarded scalar potential in Coulomb electrodynamics and what's the use?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-invariance, gauge

In Coulomb gauge electrodynamics with potential $(\phi,\vec{A})$ and source $(\rho,\vec{J})$ we obtain the Poisson's equation for the scalar equation and the wave equation with transverse current source $\vec{J}_t$ for the magnetic vector potential.
$$\nabla^2 \phi=\rho \tag{1}$$
$$\Box \vec{A}=\vec{J}_t \tag{2}$$

I have two related questions---

i) I can easily find retarded solutions for $(2)$ but what boundary conditions can be imposed to get retarded scalar potential solving $(1)$ given by $$\phi(t,\vec{r})_{ret}=\int\frac{\rho\left(\vec{r}',t-|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|\right)}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|}dV'\tag{3}$$

ii) In [Brill and Goodman (1967)](https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article/35/9/832/1045177/Causality-in-the-Coulomb-Gauge) it is shown that putting the ordinary "Coulomb solution" to $(1)$ given by $$\phi(t,\vec{r})=\int\frac{\rho\left(\vec{r}',t\right)}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|}dV'$$ and the retarded solution solving $(2)$ in $$\vec{E}=-\vec{\nabla} \phi-\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}\tag{4}$$
we get [Jeffimenko's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations).
What is the physical significance of the solution which I will get if I used retarded scalar potential $(3)$ and retarded solution to $(2)$ in $(4)$? I guess it would be a retarded solution with sources $(\rho,\vec{J_t})$.